# Laravel - Many To Many Polymorphic Relations

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use the Many To Many Polymorphic Relationship in laravel for the first time. In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) for it, for the DB structure it says:

```
taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

What I wonder is what is the difference between the `tag_id` and the `taggable_id`, what do we store in each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using a many-to-many polymorphic relation allows you to have a single
>   list of unique tags that are **shared across blog posts and videos**.

Having read that, I'd say `taggable_id` references either `posts.id` or `videos.id`, as "taggable" entities. Then, the `taggable_type` answers the question - is the `taggable_id` a video or a post?

Full table structure for better visualization:

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

**Example:**

**posts**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 12 | test post |
+----+-----------+
```

**videos**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 5  | test vid  |
+----+-----------+
```

**tags**

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
| 88 | programming  |
+----+--------------+
```

**taggables**

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| tag_id | taggable_id | taggable_type |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 88     | 12          | post          |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 88     | 5           | video         |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Yes, but what is then tag_id?

Comment: Well, exactly what it says: the ID of the tag, from the `tags` table. Again, a single tag can be *shared* across posts and videos.